# How can I add data from a JSON to a constant variable in Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm working in a NodeJS. I want to take data from `data.json`, a JSON file with with coords (lat and lon) and use them to bring up the weather and other stuff, using the `Open Weather API`. I'm expecting to bring that coords from the JSON and then create the objects but I get my data as undefined:

```
Official Id: undefined
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=undefined&lon=undefined&exclude=hourly,daily&appid=123
```

Here's a little example of the `data.json`:

```
[
  {
    "latjson": 1,
    "lonjson": 1,
    "IdOficina": "1"
  },
  {
    "latjson": 2,
    "lonjson": 2,
    "IdOficina": "2"
  }
]
```

and here is how I'm trying to save that data in a const

```
function calcWeather1() {
    var data = fs.readFileSync("./json/data.json", "utf8");
    /*const data = [{
        "latjson": "33.44",
        "lonjson": "-94.04",
        "IdOficina": "1"
    },
    {
        "latjson": 2,
        "lonjson": 2,
        "IdOficina": "2"
    }
    ];*/

    for (let item of data) {
        let url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${item.latjson}&lon=${item.lonjson}&exclude=hourly,daily&appid=123`;

        console.log(`Official Id: ${item.IdOficina}`);
        console.log(url);
        console.log('-----------');
    }
}
```

The issue is that, when I send the JSON data like Randy told me:

```
/*const data = [{
        "latjson": "33.44",
```

I get:

```
Official Id: 1
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=33.44&lon=-94.04&exclude=hourly,daily&appid=123
```

it works, but when I take it from a JSON file, like:

```
var data = fs.readFileSync("./json/data.json", "utf8");
```

I get

```
Official Id: undefined
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=undefined&lon=undefined&exclude=hourly,daily&appid=123
-----------
```

EDIT:
I tried bringing data as Randy told me:

```
const json = fs.readFileSync("./json/data.json", "utf8");
const data = JSON.parse(json);
for (let item of data) {...
```

and still getting `undefined`

EDIT:
Here's my `data.json`, I added the way it is structured here but here is the [file](https://github.com/martnjf/weather_stack/blob/master/json/data.json)

Comment: You do realize `undefined` is not a valid latitude right? Both lat and lon coming from your data structure are `undefined`. I would work on fixing that first.

Comment: @RandyCasburn it is a valid latitude as I added to the edit of my question, I forgot to say that

Comment: I'm simply looking at what you reported as the error: `FetchError: request...` clearly states both lat and lon are `undefined`. Unless there is a different error message that you are attempting to fix than the one you provided above, it is indisputable.

Comment: I understand you @RandyCasburn I think it is because I'm not adding the lat and lon to the constant, is that right? should I edit or create another question?

Comment: This should be simple to fix. This `const base = ...` assignment is where this happens. If you `console.log(lat, long)` just before that statement, you will see they are `undefined` there. That implies you're not parsing your data correctly. Fix that.

Comment: Yep, they are ```undefined```, how can I parse it correctly?

Comment: did you define this structure or did you get it from someplace? There is no reason to put individual objects inside a single element array (This is uneccessary: `[{
    "latjson": 1,
    "lonjson": 1,
    "IdOficina": "1"
  }]`), so I would start by removing the unneeded arrays that each object.

Comment: If you're willing to do that, I'll write up an answer to show you.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I've now change this ```[{     "latjson": 1,     "lonjson": 1,     "IdOficina": "1"   }]``` to this: ```{     "latjson": 1,     "lonjson": 1,     "IdOficina": "1"   }``` I would really appreciate the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: OP is has not parsed the JSON string from the file, adding those instructions. When reading the file, you read it in as a string, it must be parsed into a JavaScript Object. Use `JSON.parse()` to accomplish that goal.

```
const json = fs.readFileSync("./json/data.json", "utf8");
const data = JSON.parse(json);
```

Now the `data` variable contains the array of objects. If you look at the first array element and ask for its `jsonlat` it should return the correct data:

```
data[0].latjson
```

Now you are ready to continue with the below instructions:

You are not parsing the array properly. Given the comments and the change to the data structure discussed there, this is the data to parse:

```
[
  {
    "latjson": 1,
    "lonjson": 1,
    "IdOficina": "1"
  },
  {
    "latjson": 2,
    "lonjson": 2,
    "IdOficina": "2"
  }
]
```

Rather than use [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#description) you should really use [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) it will make it easier and will keep you out of trouble down the road with other coding you do.

Here is what that would look like:

```js
const fakeAPIKey = 12342456478;
const data = [{
    "latjson": "33.44",
    "lonjson": "-94.04",
    "IdOficina": "1"
  },
  {
    "latjson": 2,
    "lonjson": 2,
    "IdOficina": "2"
  }
];


for (let item of data) {
  let url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${item.latjson}&lon=${item.lonjson}&exclude=hourly,daily&appid=${fakeAPIKey}`;

  console.log(`Official Id: ${item.IdOficina}`);
  console.log(url);
  console.log('-----------');
}
```

Comment: I got another error lol, but this answers the other, thank you!

Comment: mate, should I change it to ```const lat = item.latjson;``` ?

Comment: yes - that would be it!

Comment: Mate I apologise for accepting the answer, but I get ```Successful connection
[]
Official Id: undefined
Latitude: undefined
Longitude: undefined
-----------``` do you know what can be? do I need to unaccept it? I dont know how stackoveflow works in that things

Comment: I've updated my answer to show exactly how to accomplish the goal. It should be very close to what you are attempting to accomplish.

Comment: mate, your example works perfectly, but it is not what I am expecting, because, I read a JSON file, not really a JSON that is in the ```.mjs``` file, could you tell how to read that? because I tried ```var data = fs.readFileSync("./json/data.json", "utf8");``` insted of ```const data = [{``` and I get undefined, sorry but I didnt know what the problem was, I'll edit the question

Comment: I would be guessing without seeing the actual contents of that file. Can you share the contents of that `.json` file? A portion? Does it start with `'` or `"` or `{` or `[` or a variable declaration, or something else?

Comment: Of course mate, I added it to the edit of my question, I did a smaller JSON to don't have to wait for all the data to read, but it is basically like in the question edit: ```Here's a little example of the data.json:...```

Comment: Answer edited for you.

Comment: I really apreciate your time but I did what you said and I get ```undefined:1
[
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0```

Comment: My new code looks like this: ```const json = fs.readFileSync("./json/data2.json", "utf8");
    const data = JSON.parse(json); for (let item of data) {
        let url = ... ```

Comment: As I said, "_I would be guessing_" about your file contents - you did not answer that direct set of questions about the file content - what you think is in the file is not what is in the file. I cannot help you without knowing what is precisely in that file. Put the file up on Dropbox or something and share the link to the file. I can't help otherwise.

Comment: Sure, I dont have access to dropbox here, but let me upload it to github, give me a sec

Comment: Here is my [JSON](https://github.com/martnjf/weather_stack/blob/master/json/data.json)

Comment: you have a space at the beginning of that file - that is not valid when parsing the JSON. Remove the space and it should work fine.

Comment: I got you, is there a way to delete this spaces? I did it manually but get the same mistake

Comment: try `JSON.parse(json.trim())`

Answer (score 0):

{"cod":"400","message":"wrong latitude"} you are getting bad request response from the API. It appears from  the error message that the latitude is wrong

Comment: I edited my question, I would really apreciate if you could check it out :)