# How can I insert data from a JSON to a const variable in NodeJS for using an API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, tedious

I'm currently working on a NodeJS project, this takes data from a JSON and then use it to take weather stuff form an API, after that I want to save it to a DB, I already asked [about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70083563/how-can-i-add-data-from-a-json-to-a-constant-variable-in-node-js) and that question helped me fixing some problems but now I have some others, I'm sending the data to a constant but the issue is that I don't know why am I getting an error in the JSON Parse, I want to use the lat and lon from the JSON (I have like a hundred data coords) and insert it into the const, any help would help, This is the error I'm getting

```
Successful connection
[]
undefined:1
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

here is my function that takes data from JSON and gets data from the API:

```
async function calcWeather() {
  fs.readFile("./json/data.json","utf8", function (err, data) {
    if(err) throw err;
    data2 = JSON.parse(data);
  
    console.log(typeof data2);
    for (let item of data2) {
      
      let base = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${item.latjson}&lon=${item.lonjson}&appid=${api_key}&units=metric&lang=sp`;
      
      fetch(base)
        .then((responses) => {
          return responses.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
          var myObject = {
            Id_Oficina: item.IdOficina,
            Humedad: data.main.humidity,
            Nubes: data.clouds.all,
            Sensacion: data.main.feels_like,
            Temperatura: data.main.temp,
            Descripcion: data.weather.description,
          };
          // validation and saving data to array
          if (myObject.Temperatura < 99) {
            lstValid.push(myObject);
          }
        });
    }
  });
  console.log(lstValid);
}
```

here is the JSON where I take the data:

```
[
  {
    "latjson": 1,
    "lonjson": 1,
    "IdOficina": "1"
  },
  {
    "latjson": 2,
    "lonjson": 2,
    "IdOficina": "2"
  }
]
```

I think the issue is in the parse, but I don't get what I am doing wrong

Comment: https://jsonlint.com/ you can use this site to validate your json. very useful and saves a ton of time. there are other sites too but i have been using this for a long time. if you copy in the text of your json that you are trying to parse and it fails their check then you know that is the issue

Comment: @nathanhayfield it is a valid JSON mate

Comment: @traktor I'm getting the same mistake mate :(

Comment: @traktor sure, I edited

Comment: Try logging some (using `.substring` if needed) of the JSON data read using `readData` - it is not what is shown in the post because that parses successfully. You may have a file encoding issue or invisible bad characters (such as zero width or non-breaking space characters) at the start of data.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are reading the file with `fs.readFile`, you are getting a string and not a JavaScript object. You would need to parse it entirely in order to be able to manipulate the content (you seem to be parsing the first character only):

```
const fs = require('fs')
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('./data.json')
let data = JSON.parse(rawdata)
```

Personally, I think it's way easier to require it (no need to use `fs`):

```
const jsonData = require('./json/data.json')

async function calcWeather() {
    for (let item of jsonData) {
       // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I change it to ```async function calcWeather() {
  let rawdata = fs.readFileSync("./json/data.json");
  let data2 = JSON.parse(rawdata);

  // fs.readFile("./json/data.json", "utf8", function (err, data) {
  //   if (err) throw err;
  //   data2 = JSON.parse(data /*[0]*/);

  //   console.log(typeof data2);
    for (let item of data2) {
      let base = `https:``` and I'm getting the same message error :c

Comment: What I said was that you don't need the `readFile` at all. If you `require('./data.json')`, you will have an object. I'll edit the answer to include your function as example.

Comment: I'm having some issues with ```require```, can I change it to ```import```?

Comment: I don't think that is the problem at all. Maybe post here a pastebin with all your function `calcWeather` and I may be able to help... Have you removed the readFile code? In which line is the error happening?

Comment: Sure, here is the [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/ghDZjMte) the error know is ```TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".json" ``` with the things you told me

Comment: Note there is a difference between using `require` and reading the JSON from file -  `require` will cache the first data it reads and not (automatically) respond to changes of JSON data on the file system

Comment: Just to clarify, are you using import or require in the rest of your code?

Comment: @traktor 's comment is valid! But since the file seems to be static, I would say using require is fine in this case.

Comment: @MartínJF you can't import JSON with ES modules (using import). For what you need to use `readFile`.
However, if you can use CommonJS modules (require), the code samples I provided work without a problem.
The error you have now in the pastebin you sent is because you are not allowed to import JSON the way you did.